# only one object being set to app.set() Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, for-loop

Good Afternoon,
I am using the MERN stack to making a simple invoice application.
I have a function that runs 2 forEach() that goes through the invoices in the DB and the Users. if the emails match then it gives the invoices for that user.
When I log DBElement to the console it works, it has the proper data, but when I log test1 to the console (app.get()) it only has one object not both.

```js
// forEach() function
 function matchUserAndInvoice(dbInvoices, dbUsers) {
    dbInvoices.forEach((DBElement) => {
      dbUsers.forEach((userElement) => {

        if(DBElement.customer_email === userElement.email){
           const arrayNew = [DBElement];
        arrayNew.push(DBElement);
        app.set('test', arrayNew);
        }
      })
    })

  }
  
  // end point that triggers the function and uses the data.
   app.get('/test', async (req,res) => {

      const invoices = app.get('Invoices');
      const users = await fetchUsersFromDB().catch((e) => {console.log(e)});

       matchUserAndInvoice(invoices,users,res);
       
      const test1 = await app.get('test');
      console.log(test1);
      res.json(test1);
    })
```

Comment: Note also that `matchUserAndInvoice()` is asynchronous and you are NOT waiting for it to finish so even if the rest of the code was correct (which it isn't), then your `console.log(test1)` would not show the results of the previous call to `matchUserAndInvoice()` because it won't have completed it's work yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function matchUserAndInvoice(dbInvoices, dbUsers) {
    let newArray = [];
    
    dbInvoices.forEach((DBElement) => {
      dbUsers.forEach(async(userElement) => {

        if(DBElement.customer_email === userElement.email){
         
          newArray.push(DBElement);
          app.set('test', newArray);
        }
      })
    })

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

`app.set('test', DBElement);` overrides the existing DBElement, so only the last matching `DBElement` is shown in `test1`.

If you want to have `test` correspond to all matching `DBElement`, you should set it to an array, and then append a new `DBElement` to the array each time it matches inside the for-loop:

```js
        if(DBElement.customer_email === userElement.email){
            let newArray = await app.get('test');
            newArray.push(DBElement);
            app.set('test', newArray);
        }
```

Comment: whats the best way to save DBElement to have it be accessible to another route?

Comment: @AS10 added example of adding new element to array.

Comment: I added what I have, right now in my original code,  it just renders the same object twice, there are two different objects in DBElement

Comment: @AS10 you should not have `const arrayNew = [DBElement];`, you should get the initial value from `await app.get('test');` as I have shown.

Comment: app.get(test) is not an array its just an object.

Comment: I am posting the answer, I just had to initialize  an array at the top of the function.